# MS bot reply twice

Tags: botframework

At `localhost` in the emulator, as soon as I connect to the bot I get the sign in card but in the `azure` registered channel web chat I don't get the sign in card instead I need to type something then I get it twice. [webchat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAD0x.png)
How do I get the sign in card without the need to type something in chat.
I've turned the always on option and it still didn't help.

The sign in card come from the community auth middleware [Link here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.AzureAdAuthentication)
and i use the following code in the onTurn's bot class:

```
public async Task OnTurn(ITurnContext turnContext)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.UserHasJustJoinedConversation() || turnContext.Activity.UserHasJustSentMessage())
        {
            var state = turnContext.GetConversationState<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            var dialogCtx = dialogs.CreateContext(turnContext, state);


            await dialogCtx.Continue();
            if (!turnContext.Responded)
            {

                await dialogCtx.Begin("mainDialog", new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["Value"] = turnContext.Activity.Text
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

and i also use the following two functions

```
public static bool UserHasJustSentMessage(this Activity activity)
    {

        return activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message;
    }

public static bool UserHasJustJoinedConversation(this Activity activity)
    {

        return activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate && activity.MembersAdded.FirstOrDefault().Id != activity.Recipient.Id;
    }
```

Comment: If you want help on that kind of case, add at least the implementation of your code which is doing this prompt for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `ConversationUpdate`s that get emitted when a conversation starts: one for the user joining the conversation and one for the bot joining the conversation so you need filter out the bot's one:

```
public static bool UserHasJustJoinedConversation(this Activity activity)
{

    return activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate
        && activity.MembersAdded.Any(channelAccount => channelAccount.Id != "YourBotName");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, now I do get the sign in card as soon as i open the web chat.